# Oracle - Can't use * sign with other column in select clause

Tags: oracle, select

Sorry if it's trivial, but selecting column with `*` sign isn't working always, and I don't find reference to this behavior.

I can select table `A` and column `col` with the following statements:

`select * from A;` and `select col from A;` and `select aa.col,aa.* from A aa;`

But I can't view it together:

```
select *,col from A;
```

Will result in error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found`

```
select col,* from A aa;
```

Will result in error `ORA-00936: missing expression`

Why i must use the alias for `*` sign ?

```
select col,aa.* from A aa;
```

Why are the errors so misleading?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126854) helps

Comment: @Aleksej I don't find restriction in select_list

Comment: There's no explicit restriction written, but if you follow the diagram, you see that you can use `*` only with nothing else in select list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The restriction is not so clearly stated in documentation, but you can find it by following [this diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126854).

[image]

Here you see that if you use the `*`, you can't use anything else in select list

Answer (score 3):

The [syntax diagram for `select`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) shows:

[image]

The outermost path of that shows the plain, unprefixed `*` all-column wildcard on its own, and there is no loop back around for additional column expressions - all paths with a comma (to separate terms) are distinct from that plain `*` path.

On the inner path that *does* allow a comma, and thus multiple expressions, you can only use `.*` prefixed by a table/view/alias, and can then follow (or precede) that with other expressions.

(I really thought that was stated more clearly somewhere, but I can't find it anywhere in recent documentation...)

> Why i must use the alias for * sign ?
>
> ```
> select col,aa.* from A aa;
> ```

That isn't *quite* accurate; you don't have to use an alias, you can use the table name directly if it isn't aliased, so this is also valid:

```
select col,A.* from A;
```

---

There is a school of thought that you shouldn't use a wildcard anyway, at least for anything except an ad hoc query - it's better to list all of the required column name explicitly, prefixed with the appropriate table name/alias particularly if there is a join, for clarity and to avoid unexpected issues with tables being modified. That's rather outside the scope of this question though *8-)

Answer (score 1):

> Why are the errors so misleading?

The errors are correct. They just don't guess what you are trying to do. After

```
select *
```

the next keyword should be `from`, so anything else gives

```
FROM keyword not found where expected
```

After `,` there should be a valid expression such as a column name, not `*` which is unexpected, so you get

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Perhaps it would be nice if Oracle wrote a special error message about the incorrect use of `*`, but so far they have not. You could propose it on the [Oracle Database Ideas](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/database-ideas) forum.